# mdadm raid resync

Tags: raid, mdadm, synchronization

i have a raspberry pi with two USB thumb drives that are in a mirror raid array and store my data that I share using Nextcloud. Now randomly, I caught today that one USB drive LED was flashing without any obvous reason so I connected to my pi and did `cat /proc/mdstat` and what I saw was:

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] 
md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[2]
      120109056 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      [===================>.]  check = 99.9% (120103296/120109056) finish=0.0min speed=18842K/sec
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

I was awatching it just before it reached 99.9% but this is the laast resync message I caught, after this it looks like:

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] 
md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[2]
      120109056 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
  bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

Now, how do I find out why the resync happened and if one of the drives is actually bad and should be replaced? `sda1 and`sdb1`still looks good with`lsblk`:

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    1 119.3G  0 disk  
└─sda1        8:1    1 114.6G  0 part  
  └─md0       9:0    0 114.6G  0 raid1 /mnt/usb
sdb           8:16   1 114.6G  0 disk  
└─sdb1        8:17   1 114.6G  0 part  
  └─md0       9:0    0 114.6G  0 raid1 /mnt/usb
mmcblk0     179:0    0  29.2G  0 disk  
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   256M  0 part  /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0    29G  0 part  /
```

**UPDATE:**

There's no `/etc/charray` but `/etc/cron.d/mdadm` looks like:

```
$ cat /etc/cron.d/mdadm 
#
# cron.d/mdadm -- schedules periodic redundancy checks of MD devices
#
# Copyright © martin f. krafft <madduck@madduck.net>
# distributed under the terms of the Artistic Licence 2.0
#

# By default, run at 00:57 on every Sunday, but do nothing unless the day of
# the month is less than or equal to 7. Thus, only run on the first Sunday of
# each month. crontab(5) sucks, unfortunately, in this regard; therefore this
# hack (see #380425).
57 0 * * 0 root if [ -x /usr/share/mdadm/checkarray ] && [ $(date +\%d) -le 7 ]; then /usr/share/mdadm/checkarray --cron --all --idle --quiet; fi
```

which refers to `/usr/share/mdadm/checkarray` which is a script that doesn't produce ant output to stdout when it is run.

Comment: Do you have an /etc/cron.d/checkarray or /etc/cron.d/mdadm file, and if so what is in it?

Comment: probably just a periodic check but you can see if there were any errors in dmesg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a cron job run in the early hours of the morning of the first sunday of the month which does a full check of the array. The OP caught it running.

Comment: Okay, nothing to worry about then? It wasn't Sunday early hours in my time zone but for UTC, that is about true!

Comment: Almost certainly nothing to worry about.